# Multiple Parameters MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am making a library-like website. In this library an article can have a category, and said category can have up to 2 parent categories, like: "World > Country > City".

I want to keep all the displaying of views to a single Controller for all articles, named `LibraryController`. And the 2 actions being used are `Article(string id)` and `Category(string[] ids)`

To view an article called "The Templar Order" the user must input: `/library/article/the-templar-order`

Alright, so now the categories. I have 2 approaches in my head, this example is to view the "City" category:

1. The simple approach: `/library/world-country-city`
2. The one I would like: `/library/world/country/city`
3. The one I do NOT want, as it becomes too clumsy: `/library/category/world/country/city`

But I am a bit confused as to how I would go about creating a route that takes 3 parameters and essentially no action. And except for the first parameter "world" the rest should be optional, like this: `"/library/world/"` > `"/library/world/country/"` > `"/library/world/country/city/"`

So how would I go about creating such a route ?

**Solution**

RouteConfig.cs

```
// GET library/article/{string id}
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Articles",
    url: "Library/Article/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Library", action = "Article", id = "" }
    );

// GET library/
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LibraryIndex",
    url: "Library/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Library", action = "Index" }
    );

// GET library/category/category/category etc.
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Category",
    url: "Library/{*categories}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Library", action = "Category" }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following two routes.

```
// GET library/article/the-templar-order
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Articles",
     url: "Library/Article/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Library", action = "Article" }
 );

// GET library/world/country/city
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Category",
     url: "Library/{*categories}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Library", action = "Category" }
 );
```

And a slight modification to the target action

```
public ActionResult Category(string categories) {
    categories = categories ?? string.Empty;
    var ids = categories.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //...other code
}
```

Comment: sry I was bit too quick at accepting the answer. I am receiving a "Resource not found" on anything besides /library/world/country/city. Meaning a url such as /library/world causes an error.

Comment: Show the order in which you mapped the routes. the order is important because first match wins. this probably means that another route is catching the url before it can be handled.

Comment: thanks mate, updated the question with the final solution... Now it works perfectly... It was the ordering of the mapped routes that were indeed causing the issue...

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help. Remember that specific routes need to be mapped before more general routes. Happy coding!!!